# Use npm install offline

Tags: node.js, npm

My raspberry pi zero is a hotspot and didn't have a internet connection.

It's why I would like to install a npm package in my own computer and then drop this package into my raspberry by using an sftp connection.

I have tried to install the git package and then transfer it with sftp and try a "npm i folder/" but this didn't work.

I hope someone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "by using an sftp connection" but that involves a network connection? You may have difficulty doing this maneuver because of platform differences. Best course of action would be to route network to your rpi, or build a complete application and copy that. It depends on what you are installing, what for..

Comment: Yes I'm having a wifi connection that is used to have a hotspot with another device.
And I need to install in ssh an npm package in my own computer and then tranfer it in sftp to my RPI and and don't know then how to install this package when I'm having the folder in my RPI.
Sorry If it was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can copy node_modules folder content,

$ npm install -g local-npm

$npm set registry http://127.0.0.1:5080

or to switch back to the default npm online repo

$ npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org

$ npm install --save lodash bluebird

finally, check http://localhost:5080/_browse to see your archived repos

Comment: Thanks a lot but unfortunately, I could not install local-npm cause I haven't the internet connection on my raspberry pi now but thanks a lot, I will install this package for other project.